# Expectation value in spin-orbit coupling

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, perturbation-theory

So I was just trying a question where it asked to find the Energy shift due to a spin-orbit coupling Hamiltonian to first order using perturbation theory.
The Hamiltonian is $$H_{LS} = \frac{Ze^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0c^2m_e^2r^3}\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\,,$$ so to get the energy shift it's $$\Delta E = \left<H_{LS}\right>\,.$$
The confusion I have with this is whether I can say that, ignoring all the constants, I can just write $$\left<\frac{1}{r^3}\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\right>$$ is the same as $$\left<\frac{1}{r^3}\right>\left<\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\right>$$ because $\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}$ doesn't depend on $r$ and then this will simplify the problem a lot as the previous part of the question is finding $\left<\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\right>$. Part of me wants to just go ahead and say that that's just fine but I'm not sure if it's mathematically/physically justified?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true in general that $\left<\frac{1}{r^3}\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\right> = \left<\frac{1}{r^3}\right>\left<\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S}\right>$, 
but it $is$ true if you're evaluating the matrix elements between eigenstates of the total angular momentum $\vec{J}$.

To see this, use $\vec{J}^2 = \left(\vec{L} + \vec{S}\right)^2$ to write $\vec{L}\cdot\vec{S} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{J}^2 - \vec{L}^2 - \vec{S}^2\right)$.  Then just note that the right hand side can be replaced by a pure number, $j(j+1) - \ell(\ell+1) - s(s+1)$, when acting on a simultaneous eigenvector of $\vec{J}^2$,  $\vec{L}^2$ and $\vec{S}^2$.