# Calculation in Spin-Orbital Coupling for Hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was calculating the spin-orbital correction in the fine structure of Hydrogen, but then bumped into an irritating problem.

In the process of calculation, I must calculate $\langle n,l,j,m_j|\frac{\overrightarrow{S}\cdot\overrightarrow{L}}{r^3}|n,l,j,m_j\rangle $. In all of the textbooks and posts I read, they simply calculate the term as $\langle\overrightarrow{S}\cdot\overrightarrow{L}\rangle\langle\frac{1}{r^3}\rangle$.

Since I consider $\frac{1}{r^3}$ an operator, I am wondering how the expectation value of the product of operators can be treated as the product of the expectation values.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186126/expectation-value-in-spin-orbit-coupling/418515#418515

Comment: @PaulG Thank you! I thought I read all Q&As on the Physics Stack Exchange to prevent a duplicate question, but I failed to do so. Thanks for pointing out an appropriate post!

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the interesting question.
I guess that you can calculate the term as the product of expected values because the radial operator $1/r^3$ does not affect the angular part of the states, since you use the basis of spin-angular functions to describe the wave function (e.g. Eq. 5.3.8 in Sakurai "Modern Quantum Mechanics")

I hope this helps to clarify your question, or at least, to shed some light.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Your answer definitely helped me out!